# Why can't I run ausearch (part of auditd) remotely over SSH?

Tags: ssh, sudo, auditd

Any idea why the following doesn't work? It hangs with no output.

```
desktop$ ssh myserver "sudo ausearch -k my_key"
```

However, the following works. It outputs the auditing history of this key from auditd.

```
desktop$ ssh myserver
myserver$ sudo ausearch -k my_key
```

The following also works. (Meaning, sudo is not currently set to require a password.)

```
desktop$ ssh myserver "sudo ls"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you logon as a normal user you might not have `/sbin` in your $PATH, which means that ausearch might not be found. To try this, specific /sbin/ausearch manually in your command line. For some commands you also require ssh to aquire a tty, you accomplish this with the `-t` flag, so to try this out, type:

```
ssh -t myserver "sudo /sbin/ausearch -k my_key"
```

To fully emulate a logged in session you can also call sudo with the `-i` flag, and then you can probably omit the /sbin (since it worked in your logged in session), as this:

```
ssh -t myserver "sudo -i ausearch -k my_key"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the -t option to SSH, try adding `--input-logs` to the command (see the man page)

Ref: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1032706#c13

Comment: This does seem like the more correct answer, not doing any workarounds. You mean `--input-logs`, though?

Comment: Yes, thank you Amir (now corrected)